# Ruby script lookup method return nil class?

Tags: ruby, protocol-buffers, suse

I have a ruby script as shown below:

```
require 'google/protobuf'

Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.build do
  add_message "google.protobuf.Any" do
    optional :type_url, :string, 1
    optional :value, :bytes, 2
  end
end

module Google
  module Protobuf
    Any = Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.lookup("google.protobuf.Any").msgclass
  end
end
```

The lookup call gives me `nil` class. Why does it give me `nil` class?  Whereas `google.protobuf.Any` is defined in the above block.

The error that I get when I run `ruby any_pb.rb` is:

```
any_pb.rb:15:in `<module:Protobuf>': undefined method `msgclass' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from any_pb.rb:14:in `<module:Google>'
    from any_pb.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

**Environment**: Suse s390x Big Endian

Link to environment: https://linuxone20.cloud.marist.edu/cloud/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi @sawa, sorry for not giving clarity on my question. My question is that why does lookup call give nil class whereas it should point out to google.protobuf.Any. Do you know why ?.